# Change event of Angular rangeSlider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, rangeslider

Following http://danielcrisp.github.io/angular-rangeslider/demo I created a slider to change a price value.

```
 <div range-slider min="5000000" max="1000000000" model-min="demo1.min" model-max="demo1.max"></div> {{demo1.max}}
```

In the place of `{{demo1.max}}` instead of 5000000 I want to show `5 Million`.  As the value reaches Billion, want to show like `1 Billion`. I know I have to write custom code for this, but how can I catch the change event of Angular rangeSlider? Can I change filter, filter-options from code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I catch the change event of Angular rangeSlider?

To do this, you can use on-handle-down property. It will trigger given function when you release the range handles. You can check your model values in this function and act as you wish.

```
<div range-slider on-handle-up='handleUp();' ... ></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angular rangeSlider, you can get two events

```
<div range-slider on-handle-up='handleUp();' on-handle-down="handleDown();"></div>
```

1. When to handle is grabbed `on-handle-down`
2. when handle is released `on-handle-up`